# How to write JMeter results in Azure-Event-Hub/(or any DB) in batches

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I am using JMeter JSR223 listener to write SampleResult in EventHub(message queue). I want to write the results in batches in event-hub using event-hub's batch-write api. Any idea how to do that?
I am thinking of using 2 JSR 223 listener, first listener will store the results in a csv file. 2nd listener will read from csv file in chunks of fixed size(using offset), create a batch msg json and then post it in event-hub.
I am looking for any better approach or code reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest going for your own [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) implementation as Java code will be in any case more efficient than Groovy. There are some examples of batching in i.e. [InfluxdbBackendListenerClient.java](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/166800a3ae5537d28102e5b9bbf2daaca8f00bcd/src/components/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/influxdb/InfluxdbBackendListenerClient.java)

If for some reason you will proceed with your listeners be warned about potential [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), i.e. if you will use the same file for storing the metrics and listener will be executed by 2 or more threads at a time - it will result in data loss or corruption so I would suggest using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) for storing the metrics you want to send